# Setting Java heap space Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, heap-size

i'm running trying to run an image processing code wich involves the allocation of big 3D matrices. As you've probably guessed i get the infamous Heap space error :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Now, i'm running netbeans 8.0.2 64 bit on a 64bit windows 8.1 with 16 gigs of ram.
i've already tried creating a JAVA_OPTS ambient variable as well as modifing the 
netbeans.conf file in etc folder but the max value i could set is Xmx1050m... i need more. A LOT more... is it possible to get the jvm to allocate more ( for example 8-10 gigs ) ?

Comment: You sir! get Eclipse ...

Comment: Its just better IDE - trust me, i am engineer ;)!